# Android emulator cannot connect to DNS hostname, but can connect to IP address

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my application I can connect to the server using the IP address, but when I try to connect with the DNS hostname I am not able to connect through the Android emulator. In logcat I am getting the following error:

> 07-10 10:22:42.312: I/Choreographer(848): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   07-10 10:24:00.181: I/Choreographer(848): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   07-10 10:24:02.561: E/HttpsTransport(848): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "example.com": No address associated with host name
>   07-10 10:24:02.922: I/Choreographer(848): Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can see two issues here.

1. You are trying make network call in main thread. Which is not accepted from `Android 4.0`. So better you do in background thread. Though you are developing application lower than `Android 4.0` , I will recommend do in background thread.
2. You should give full server address starting with "`http://www.example.com`". If you are able to connect using IP. you should get connected via server name.